# What is the mistake in this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

```
SELECT * FROM `continue_paper`JOIN `questions`
WHERE `questions`.q_id IN
`continue_paper`.cp_qu_id AND `continue_paper`.cp_id=1
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: The mistake is in the design of the table. See about normalisation. Also, (and,arguably, related) any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing - another clue that your design is suboptimal.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `continue_paper`JOIN `questions` ON `continue_paper`.cp_id=1 ANd FIND_IN_SET(`questions`.q_id , `continue_paper`.`cp_qu_id`)

Answer (score 0):

in your code  you need  a set of values for the IN clause  in your case you have not so you should use =

```
SELECT * 
FROM continue_paper 
JOIN questions ON questions.q_id =continue_paper.cp_qu_id 
    AND continue_paper.cp_id=1
```

and you could use a ON clause instead of where

Comment: You can `JOIN` without an `ON` clause.

Comment: i have past your query in mysql but it give me following error                                      #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'questions.q_id =continue_paper.cp_qu_id
    AND continue_paper.cp_id=1 LIMIT 0' at line 3                                                                                 pleases note continue_papaer.cp_qu_id has a multiple value  i have attach pic of my database pleases check May be it helps

Comment: show me the exact code you are  really using  ..  (in my query there is not  limit )

Comment: i had got the answer and i have mention it thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

It's usually good practice to use `JOIN` with comparison operators.

I would join the tables using the foreign/primary keys, then filter it with `IN` if needed.

Specifically, I would approach it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `continue_paper` JOIN `questions`
WHERE `questions`.q_id =
`continue_paper`.cp_qu_id AND `continue_paper`.cp_id=1
```

Comment: This is correct if i have only one data on my cp_qu_id column but i have multiple string into my cp_qu_id column so this will not work for me . I hope it is useful for another person

Comment: Could you share example `cp_qu_id` content? Is it comma separated? All in all this cannot be a good design choice. For once the `IN` in SQL doesn't work like `in` in Python. I'm also thinking about the scenario that `q_id` is `1` and `cp_qu_id` is `15,35` which will be a false positive due to the 1 at the beginning.